# Using Visual Studio Code to run a build command

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run Visual Studio Code to run a C program. When I press Command-Shift-B, it always opens up a menu and I have to click on the highlighted entry of press enter again for it to actually build.

Is there a way that I can just automatically build it and not have to select this, as I find myself doing this hundreds of times:

[image]

Comment: Setup a "tasks.json" file: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

Comment: @UnholySheep -- thanks, it's in Terminal -> Configure Default Build Task.